# Which of the following language satisfies the grammar?

Tags: grammar, rdp

I'm kinda new to RDP/Pairwise Disjoint Test and this is just a sample problem. I already have the answer and I would just like to verify if this is correct.

Grammar:

```
<GU> ::= du<GU>bi<MI> | <HO> | ru
<MI> ::= ra | fa | <HO>
<HO>::= bi<HO> | bi
```

Solution:

will generate a sting of "bi" OR one "bi"
 will generate one "ra" OR one "fa" OR (string of "bi" OR one "bi")

So  will generate

```
du <GU> bi {ra | fa | {bi's | bi} } | {bi's | bi} | ru
```

Here are the sentences that can be produced by the grammar:

```
a. dudurubifabira
b. dubibibira
c. dubirubirurafa
d. dududubibibifabirabibibi
e. dududubibifarabirabibi
```

My answer is "b" and "d".

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `a` can also be generated by the language:

```
   <GU>
-> du<GU>bi<MI>
-> dudu<GU>bi<MI>bi<MI>
-> dudurubi<MI>bi<MI>
-> dudurubifabi<MI>
-> dudurubifabira
```

Otherwise, your end result seems to be correct. I'd be careful about saying a "bi" will generate something though, since it's a terminal.